# React Form state and trimming value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I have a form with a couple of fields and I want to trim the values entered by the user on tab out. However with the below code, I am unable to enter any spaces at all. I have the relevant code below.

What do I need to do so that user is able to enter any data? (Even with leading/trailing spaces... just that on tab out, it should get trimmed and shown to the user).

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
        fName: '',
        lName: ''
    });
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    setForm({
        ...form,
        [name]: value.trim()
    })
}
    
    
<Input 
    type="text"
    value={form.fName}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onClick={handleChange}
/>  

<Input 
    type="text"
    value={form.lName}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onClick={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Trim the values when you submit your form

Comment: yeah actually that was one of the options I was thinking...but just that user would not get any feedback on the screen if that is done

Comment: you can `trim` when you hit enter  : `onKeyPress={(e) => {if (e.key === "Enter") {setForm({
        ...form,
        [name]: e.target.value.trim()
    })`

Answer (score 2):

You can use onBlur event. Basically you can have a method just for **trimming**(most of the time it is used for validation).
Here is an example how it should looks:

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
    fName: '',
    lName: ''
});
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    setForm({
        ...form,
        [name]: value,
    })
}

const handleBlur = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    setForm({
        ...form,
        [name]: value.trim()
    })
}
    
    
<Input 
    type="text"
    value={form.fName}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onClick={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
/>  

<Input 
    type="text"
    value={form.lName}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onClick={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
/>
```

If you are not familiar with the blur event [here is a doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

Some nice [article](https://linguinecode.com/post/onblur-vs-onchange-react-text-inputs) too

Answer (score 0):

try onBlur event:

```
export default function App() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: ""
  });
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  return (
    <input
      value={form.fName}
      name="fName"
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={() => {
        // move in a separate function
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setForm({ ...form, [name]: form[name].trim() });
      }}
    />
  );
}
```