# Await setState in an async function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

I know I should normally use useEffect for something like this, but in this case I don't see how this can be done, so I tried to make my functions await the setState, which turns out to be impossible (I think?). The code I have now:

```
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [passwordCheck, setPasswordCheck] = useState("");

  const loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(username.length);
    await trimInputs();
    console.log(username.length);
    /* rest of the logic */
  };

  const registerUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await trimInputs();
    /* rest of the logic */
  };

  /**
   * Trims the user inputs in order to prevent submitting usernames and passwords with trailing spaces
   */
  const trimInputs = () => {
    setUsername((prev) => prev.trimEnd());
    setPassword((prev) => prev.trimEnd());
    setPasswordCheck((prev) => prev.trimEnd());
  };
```

username, password and passwordCheck take values from input fields, which update onChange. So it would be wasteful and weird for the user if a useEffect trimmed the whitespaces after each key press. Therefore I tried to make it only trim the values when login or register function is called. But it doesn't work in its current form, both console.logs return the same numbers and the State is only updated after the function is executed.

I know I could make the trimInputs function take the states and return trimmed copies for later use in the two functions, but I don't know if that's the correct way to do it and I wanted it all to be the same as in the input fields.

Comment: How can you `await`  the `trimInputs` function if it's not declared as `async`? Also, this smees like you're abusing the `useState`. You should have trimmed the inputs when setting them in the first place. Also, if you used proper `<form>` and `<input>` elements with the `required` attribute, this should not be a problem. The HTML form submission logic should be taking care of the validation part.

Comment: So the only way to do that is to get the values from the form using new FormData? Because currently I have this on each of the inputs:


onChange={(e) => {
                      setUsername(e.target.value);
                    }}


So the only time I can trim this without confusing the user is when it's being submitted, which is the action in either loginUser or registerUser.

Comment: You can always prevent the form from submitting inside the `onsubmit` handler, alter the request data, and re-send it with the properly formatted values.

Comment: Alternatively, you can [call `onblur`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73402447/1762224) to handle updating the state of the form inputs.

Comment: onBlur is great, thank you! I only had to add `onBlur={trimInputs}` to the inputs and remove some bloat from the functions

Answer (score 0):

You should use refs instead of multiple states. They are much easier to manage.

In the example below, the form will only submit if the username and password fields are populated the passwords match.

When `blur` is called, the current `ref` is updated.

```js
const { useCallback, useRef } = React;

const App = () => {
  // Refs are easier to handle vs useState
  const usernameRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordVerifyRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    const form = e.target;
    
    const passwordInput = form.elements.password;
    const passwordVerifyInput = form.elements['password-verify'];
    
    // Set error text and prevent submission...
    if (passwordInput.value !== passwordVerifyInput.value) {
      e.preventDefault();
      passwordVerifyInput.nextElementSibling.textContent = 'Passwords do not match';
      return;
    } else {
      passwordVerifyInput.nextElementSibling.textContent = '';
    }

    // Remove this to allow the form to submit naturally...
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(...[...e.target.elements].map(e => e.value));
  }, []);
  
  const trimInput = useCallback((ref) => {
    ref.current.value = ref.current.value.trim();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Register new account</h2>
      <form className="register-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username-input">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username-input" name="username" required
          ref={usernameRef} onBlur={() => trimInput(usernameRef)} />
        <label htmlFor="password-input">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password-input" name="password" required
          ref={passwordRef} onBlur={() => trimInput(passwordRef)} />
        <label htmlFor="password-verify-input">Verifiy Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password-verify-input" name="password-verify" required
          ref={passwordVerifyRef} onBlur={() => trimInput(passwordVerifyRef)} />
        <span className="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.register-form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0.25rem;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.register-form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.register-form label:after {
  content: ':';
}

.register-form button[type="submit"] {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.error {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

input:invalid {
  border-color: #900;
  background-color: #fdd;
}

input:focus:invalid {
  outline: none;
}

/* This is the style of our error messages */
.error {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;

  font-size: 80%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #900;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.error.active {
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```